# Retrieving JSON data from Wikipedia API using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, api, wikimedia

I have tried every combination I could find on here and the Wikimedia API site, still I can't seem to get any data returned. This is my code,

```
$('#go').click(function () {
    var str = $("#input").val();
    var fullstr = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=search&srnamespace=0&srsearch=' + str + '&srprop=snippet&format=json&callback=json';
    $.getJSON(fullstr, function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
  });
```

I have tested it up until the getJSON call and it seems to be working, but I don't seem to be getting anything from the call. (The final alert() is just to check for any object being returned).

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using something like Chrome to debug - have you checked the Network tab in the debugger to see exactly what was sent and returned?

Comment: @F.Moss I think  Its due to cross-origin header problem

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be helpful to you, while framing a URL you need to pass **origin=** *

```js
$(document).ready(function(){              
     $("#searchWiki").click(function(){
          var q = document.getElementById("searchid").value;
          $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&gsrlimit=15&generator=search&origin=*&gsrsearch=" + q, function(data){
     console.log(data)
     });
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="search">                    
         <input id="searchid" class="input-lg" name="gsrsearch" type="text" placeholder="search Wiki" autocomplete="off"/>
         <button id="searchWiki" class="btn-lg btn-info">Search</button>                          
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the **origin=*** parameter in your request, to prevent the cross origin error. Something like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srnamespace=0&srsearch=' + str + '&srprop=snippet&format=json&callback=json&origin=*
```